# $f(x) = 24x^4 + 30x^3 + 18x^2 + 8x + 2$ find the degree modulo $12$, $6$ and $2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

I started by saying that $12 = 2^2 \times 3$ and tried to find solutions for $0 (\mod 2)$ but I think it is undefined so, I couldn't go any further. Could someone please explain?

Comment: Hint: $30\equiv 6\mod 12$...

Comment: Hint: $f$ is the zero polynomial modulo $2$. What is the degree of the zero polynomial?

Answer (score 0):

A polynomial is defined by its coefficients. When reducing modulo $n$, you reduce each of the coefficients modulo $n$, so when you reduce modulo $2$, you get that all of the coefficients are $0$. Thus this polynomial is the zero polynomial when reduced modulo $n$. Now check in your textbook or course note for what the degree of the zero polynomial is defined to be.